# Graph In-degree Calculation from Adjacency-list

Tags: algorithm, graph, asymptotic-complexity

I came across this question in which it was required to calculate in-degree of each node of a graph from its adjacency list representation.

```
for each u
   for each Adj[i] where i!=u
     if (i,u) ∈ E
         in-degree[u]+=1
```

Now according to me its time complexity should be `O(|V||E|+|V|^2)` but the solution I referred instead described it to be equal to `O(|V||E|)`.

Please help and tell me which one is correct.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than O(|V||E|), the complexity of computing indegrees is O(|E|). Let us consider the following pseudocode for computing indegrees of each node:

```
for each u
  indegree[u] = 0;

for each u
  for each v \in Adj[u]
    indegree[v]++;
```

First loop has linear complexity O(|V|). For the second part: for each v, the innermost loop executes at most |E| times, while the outermost loop executes |V| times. Therefore the second part appears to have complexity O(|V||E|). In fact, the code executes an operation once for each edge, so a more accurate complexity is O(|E|).

Comment: I am not bit clear. The outer loop in second part has to be executed |V| times and we cant avoid it right? May I know how then O|VE| becomes O|E| ?

Comment: Yes the outer loop is bound to execute |V| times but the execution of inner loop depend on the no of edges adjacent to that vertex.. which would be less than |E| ( excluding complete graph case). To visualise this , think of finding indegree as looking at all edges. So the complexity is proportional is the no of edges in the graph is O( |E|)

Comment: Hi, the reasoning that it should be O(|E|) seems fine. But as you said, the outer loop does run |V| times. So, while doing complexity computations, do we not take into account the loops where nothing happens? Like `for i in (0,n): do nothing` has complexity as `n` or `1`?

Comment: Also, should the complexity be `O(|E|)` or `O(|E| + |V|)`, since we need to visit all the vertex rows in `Adj(G)` at least once?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)Graphs.html, Section 4.2, with an adjacency list representation,

> Finding predecessors of a node u is extremely expensive, requiring looking through every list of every node in time O(n+m), where m is the total number of edges.

So, in the notation used here, the time complexity of computing the in-degree of a node is `O(|V| + |E|)`.

This can be reduced at the cost of additional space of using extra space, however. The Wiki also states that

> adding a second copy of the graph with reversed edges lets us find all predecessors of u in O(d-(u)) time, where d-(u) is u's in-degree.

An example of a package which implements this approach is the Python package [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/). As you can see from the [constructor](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/d5c12bd269495e09a4faf4792e1d1ffb357bb7f0/networkx/classes/digraph.py#L260) of the `DiGraph` object for directional graphs, `networkx` keeps track of both `self._succ` and `self._pred`, which are dictionaries representing the successors *and* predecessors of each node, respectively. This allows it to compute each node's `in_degree` efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

`O(|V|+|E|)` is the correct answer, because you visit each vertex in `O(|V|)` and each time you visit a fraction of the edges so `O(|E|)` in total, also usually `|E|>>|V|` so `O(|E|)` is also correct