# Calculating Outdegree and Indegree of Adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, graph, degrees

### Question

> Calculate time complexity in calculating Outdegree and Indegree of Adjacency list.

#### My Approach/Doubt

Let Adj[] be an array of size V where V=No. of vertices  in a directed graph
for representing adjacency list.

I know that ,

> Outdegree of vertex u (u belongs to V) is actually the length of Adj[u]

and

> Indegree of vertex u (u belongs to V) is actually the count of u in list Adj.

In both the cases , i think the time complexity should be theta (V*E)

Where V=no. of vertices

```
  E=no. of edges
```

because for calculating outdegree,we scan all vertices and under each vertices we scan all the edges of that vertices.

Then why it is Thrta (V+E)

Please correct me where i am wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this answer for your indegree related query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930344/graph-in-degree-calculation-from-adjacency-list

Answer (score 1):

Okay, lets say we have V vertices and E edges.
In both bidirectional and unidirectional graph, for each edge E<sub>i</sub>, we get two Vertices V<sub>1</sub>, V<sub>2</sub>. We can easily get the direction of the edge and update the outdegree and indegree counter of a certain vertex.

Example:

Vertices: 1, 2, 3, 4
Edges: 1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 1, 2 -> 3
Outdegree: 0 0 0 0
Indegree: 0 0 0 0

Pass 1:
Edge 1 -> 2
Outdegree: 1 0 0 0
Indegree: 0 1 0 0

Pass 2:
Edge 2 -> 4
Outdegree: 1 1 0 0
Indegree: 0 1 0 1

Pass 3:
Edge 3 -> 1
Outdegree: 1 1 1 0
Indegree: 1 1 0 1

Pass 4:
Edge 2 -> 3
Outdegree: 1 2 1 0
Indegree: 1 1 1 1

So here, we need to run a loop through each edge and each vertex exactly once thus resulting in complexity (V + E).

Answer (score 0):

we can allocate an array arr[] of size |V| and initialize its entries to zero. Then we only need to scan the lists in Adj once, incrementing arr [u] when we see u in the lists.

The values in arr[] will be the out-degrees of every vertex. This can be done in Θ (|V| + |E|) time with Θ (|V|) additional storage.